# NSPredicate Regex error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex, nspredicate

I'm dealing with a document management page. I used `NSPredicate` regular expression while got the `searchBar.text` from user inputs. An error occurred (as the image below) while the inputs are brackets in Chinese form but went well in English form. If anyone has come across this matter? Thank you.
[image]

Here is my code,crash happen to the last row.

```
NSString * searchStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileName like[cd] \'*%@*\'",searchDisplayController.searchBar.text];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:searchStr];
self.fileArrayAfterPre =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Comment: The reason for this error is that the input you use as a regex pattern contains an unpaired number of unescaped `(` and `)`. Either escape the string used as a regex pattern or just use CONTAINS as shown in the answers below.

Comment: I have acknowledge that，thank you for remind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LIKE**: It is use in wildcard expression.

**CONTAIN**: According to your question you should use the contain[cd] because it match the file with search text.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchDisplayController.searchBar.text];

    self.fileArrayAfterPre =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```